# COGNOS make the join conditional between query subjects

Tags: cognos

In COGNOS, when I create a 1...1 relationship between 2 query subjects A and B, is the relationship always in effect? Or is there a way to say only force the relationship when I am querying A, but when I query B, give me all records from B and ignore A.

This is important because for me, B is a prompt query subject based on a lookup table. so let us say A is a list of all customers and B is a lookup table for Status(Active/Inactive).
When I query B, I just want to see Active/Inactive as prompt values. I select Active and it should bring me only records from A with Active Status.

Is this possilbe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cognos uses minimized SQL as default. You can read on it in here: 
[Cognos - What Is Minimized SQL?](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m1/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_best.10.1.1.doc/c_bp-minimized_sql.html#bp-minimized_SQL)

What it basically means is that Cognos picks only the required fields in the SELECT statement. 
So, if you picked for prompt values fields from table B, it will only use (for Prompt page only) table B. 
When you execute the report assuming you have values from both table A and B, it will do the join